# Laravel / VueJs2/ Element UI (Issue with form submit)

Tags: laravel, vuejs2

I am experiencing a very strange issue with form submission when i am using Element UI framework.

I ve got checkbox:

```
  <el-checkbox v-model="checked" name="option" :value="checked">Option Selected</el-checkbox>
```

My Vue JS looks like:

```
 export default {

    data() {
        return {
            checked: false,
        };
    }
};
```

When i am sending a form using Laravel the option in response is null.

Response:

```
    array:3 [▼
    "_token" => "TOKEN"
    "name" => "fgdjdgfhj"
    "option" => null
    ]
```

Default bootstrap checkbox, and hidden inputs works. Did any of you had similar problem?

Framework i am using : http://element.eleme.io/#/en-US/component/checkbox

Comment: Just add `option` in `data()` like: `data() {
        return {
            checked: false,
            option: []
        };
    }`

Comment: Hi thanks for such a quick response but that doesn't work. 

I would like to mention the value is actually changing in Vue Dev tools but its not passing through laravel response.

Comment: Are you using `axios` for sending data or any submit method?

Comment: I am using a Larvel POST form method with {{ csrf_field() }}

Default bootstrap inputs, or checkboxes works, but when i am trying to submit data from Element framework is always null.